# Electron adding basic browser features

Tags: electron

I would like to activate basic browser features in electron like tabs, url input, contextmenu, download manager and forms autofill. Since electron based on chromium maybe there's easy way to just activate them all? Or everything has to be reimplamented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official policy of the Electron project is that browser features are left to the developer. See [#15753](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15753#issuecomment-439829993) for one such statement. In many cases browser features are implemented in Chrome/Chromium code that isn't shared with Electron.